# What is linking by Ordinal and linking by name mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been trying to compile a third party library (Mongo C++) and when trying to run my own executable against the library got error message of the form "The ordinal XXXX could not be located in the dynamic link library XYZ". So what exactly is ordinal linking and how is it different from linking by name? How can I force the use of one against the other?

Comment: You apparently need to add a manifest to your app.

Comment: AFAIK this doesn't exist in (standard) C++. Please add a tag for your implementation.

Comment: @DanielJour, I'm not sure what you mean, the Mongo C++ depend on Mongo C driver. Does it exist in C? Could that be a reason of the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows libraries can export symbols either by providing ASCII string (that will contain mangled names in case of C++) or by ordinal, that is just by integer number without any name. If something is exported by ordinal guessing method signature and it's purpose may be quite difficult so it can be considered to be a method to hide implementation details (just like not shipping debug symbols). Although there is a probability of messing indexes and breaking backwards binary compatibility. But you gain faster library loading times. You can control export method by writing module definitions file (.def):

```
EXPORTS
    ?FancyMangledMethod1@fancy_namespace@@Z @1 NONAME
    ?FancyMangledMathod2@fancy_namespace@@Z
```

`FancyMangledMethod1` will be exported with 1 ordinal, while `FancyMangledMathod2` will be exported with mangled name.

Comment: If I got it correctly this happens only on Windows. Is there a way to control it through build systems? The problem here Mongo C++ is a third party library, which means the said module definition file should contain names of all the functions, right?

Comment: `The ordinal XXXX could not be located in the dynamic link library XYZ` message is basically equivalent to `symbol not found is the specified library`. Most likely you are using wrong library version, wrong library location, wrong Windows version or your Side-by-Side assembly manifest is not correct.

Comment: the library and the program are both compiled at the same sitting, wrong library version is unlikely. On library location, I did install it in C:\Own_LIbrary and then had that path in the system path, so that is unlikely too. I do not understand when you say wrong Windows version on your Side-by-Side assembly manifest.

Comment: In general relying on dll to be located though PATH envvar is quite unreliable as it [has lowest priority for loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx). It is difficult to guess what goes wrong in your case. I think it would be better if you create a new question with detailed description of your situation.